# Kryo compatibility in Storm 0.9.1and Titan graph database 0.4.2 with apache cassandra 2.0.7 as storage backend

Tags: apache-storm, titan, kryo

We are using Storm 0.9.1 which is using Kryo 2.17 we have module which inserts data into titan graph database which internally uses Kryo 2.21 which is resulting in the following issue:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.TypeAttributeType field com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.TypeAttribute.type to com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.TypeAttribute
Serialization trace:
type (com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.TypeAttribute)**

How do we fix this issue as upgrading Kryo to 2.21 in storm results in no such method error. We have also tried downgraded Kryo to 2.17 in titan graph data base however we are facing the same issue as the above.

Answer (score 6):

Storm 0.9.1 and earlier depends on Carbonite 1.3.2 which depends on kryo 2.17. Titan relies on kryo 2.21 which is incompatible with kryo 2.17

The java class loader cannot distinguish between the two versions of kryo, causing the RuntimeException your seeing.

Storm has recently upgraded to a newer version of Carbonite which uses kryo 2.21 see this ticket:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-263

Storm 0.9.2-incubating has yet to be released, but it does solve this problem. We've had success running Storm and Titan together. So you can either run your own build of storm 0.9.2-incubating or wait until 0.9.2-incubating is officially released.

This issue was also discussed in the [Aurelius google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/aureliusgraphs/kryo%24202.21/aureliusgraphs/4IiFZ6sNPmU/yDy-E0L8lLIJ)

Comment: Storm 0.9.2-incubating depends on kryo 2.21 and has been officially released. See http://storm.incubator.apache.org/2014/06/25/storm092-released.html